# how to get the currently edited text from textbox and not the page load contents

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box which i populate with text from Db on page load, i allow user to change contents of this text box. on clicking of button when i try and access this text it gives me the same content as populated from DB.

How do i get the current text from the text box edited by the user?

i am using asp.net with C#

I am using the following code

```
page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tbox_IssueDescription.Text = "some text from db";
}
protected void btn_SaveIssue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string Status_Text = tbox_IssueDescription.Text;
}
```

**EDIT**: my Tbox looks like "some text from db" on page_lod as normal. after i edit the text to say, "some text user entered" and click the saveIssue button i still get the tbox_IssueDescription.Text value as "some text from db"

Comment: Where do you try to fill `tbox_IssueDescription.Text`? `Is in Page_Load()`?

Comment: How are you populating this Textbox from DB values? and where are you using this text box except this place.

Comment: When do fill the tbox_IssueDescription.Text? If you do it later then Page_Init() you will overwrite the data posted from your Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before fill the `tbox_IssueDescription.Text` in `Page_Load` event, make sure about posting-back.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    tbox_IssueDescription.Text = "SomethingFromDb";
```

Answer (score 3):

The Page_Load event executes on initial load and on each server side event on postback, which is probably resetting the value of your textbox.

You need to check the "IsPostback" flag before populating the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether page is  `IsPostBack`

```
page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    tbox_IssueDescription.Text = "some text from db";
}
```